# Show that $f_k'(z)=z^{k-1}$ does not converge uniformly for $|z|<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

> 1) Show that $f_k(z)=z^k/k$ converges uniformly for $|z|<1$
>
> 2) Show that $f_k'(z)=z^{k-1}$ does not converge uniformly for $|z|<1$.

My Try:

I did part 1. In part 2, I can prove that $f_k'(z)=z^{k-1}$ does not converge uniformly for $|z|\leq 1$. But how can I prove it for $|z|<1$? Can anybody please help me to figure it out?

Comment: Why downvote? explain please..

Comment: I neutralized the down voter!  So, +1 for the question.  I also posted a hint.  Please let me know how I can improve the answer as I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\left(1-\frac1k\right)^{k-1}=e^{-1}\ne 0$$